# need to calculate cumulative sum with time point checking conditions in R

Tags: time, window, conditional-statements, cumulative-sum

I am new in R and I need to generate cumulative sum with time point checking conditions.
The data sample looks like this:

```
item_id <- c(29, 643, 46, 3, 45, 352)
group_id <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2)
start_year <- c(1993,1997,1997,1999,2006,2010)
end_year <- c(2008,2009,2017,2014,2019,2019)
item_size <- c(12,30,57,123,45,7)
mydf <- data.frame(item_id, group_id, start_year, end_year, item_size)
```

[image]

And I would like to generate another column in the end, the new data should be like this:

```
item_id <- c(29, 643, 46, 3, 45, 352)
group_id <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2)
start_year <- c(1993,1997,1997,1999,2006,2010)
end_year <- c(2008,2009,2017,2014,2019,2019)
item_size <- c(12,30,57,123,45,7)
group_size <- c(12,99,99,222,267,232)
mydf <- data.frame(item_id, group_id, start_year, end_year, item_size, group_size)
```

[image]

So, my aim is to calculate the group_size for each item_id when this item is still active (be in the group). For instance, in 1993 there is only one item(29), so the group size is 12. In 1997, there are 2 items (643, 46), so the group size is the sum of these two items plus size of item29, and so on so forth.

But in 2010, the group size should be the sum of items (id=46, 3, 45, 352), not including item 29 and item 643, because these 2 items finished before 2010 and are not active anymore, so not counted in the group. So the group size of item_id 352 in year 2010 should be 57+123+45+7=232.

Therefore, the group_size should be the total size of all active items at that point.

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks